# Hide title text on input where type="image"

Tags: html, css

I’d like to use an input of type image that also has title text to be displayed when hovered over. However, this text is always displayed “behind” the image.

I define my image like this:

```css
.left {
  background-image: url("http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/flat-arrows/png32/64/000000/flat-circle-chevron-left-arrow-64-000000.png");
}
```

```html
<input type="image" class="left" id="mToggle" width="64" height="64" value=" " title="new toggle button"/>
```

The reason for the CSS class is because I’m toggling the image on click. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os7svkw1/3/).

Side note: I’ve realized that the problem only occurs in Chrome. It doesn’t appear behind in IE or Firefox.

Comment: Do you realize that `<input type="image"/>` also needs an `src` attribute with the image source? Toggle the URL instead of the class.

Comment: Pedantic note: the text is actually in front of the image, not behind it. Adding the CSS rule `img { color:white; }` demonstrates this, as seen [in this modification of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os7svkw1/3/).

Comment: I appreciate the help everyone. Any guesses as to why Chrome handled this differently than Firefox or IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<input/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

> `type="image"`: A graphical submit button. ***You must use the `src` attribute to define the source of the image and the `alt` attribute to define alternative text.*** You can use the `height` and `width` attributes to define the size of the image in pixels.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Your HTML, therefore, is invalid. You need your button to look like in the snippet below.

If you already toggle the `class` `onclick` with JavaScript, I’d suggest you drop the CSS rules and instead change the image `src` directly. Whether you make your toggle dependent on the `class`, the `alt` or the `src` attribute, is your choice.

```js
document.getElementById('mToggle').addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(this.className=='left'){
    this.src='http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/flat-arrows/png32/64/000000/flat-circle-chevron-right-arrow-64-000000.png';
    this.alt='→';
    this.className='right';
  }
  else{
    this.src='http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/flat-arrows/png32/64/000000/flat-circle-chevron-left-arrow-64-000000.png';
    this.alt='←';
    this.className='left';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="mToggle" class="left" type="image" width="64" height="64"
  src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/flat-arrows/png32/64/000000/flat-circle-chevron-left-arrow-64-000000.png"
  alt="←" value=" " title="new toggle button"/>
```

(Use the JS code above or whatever the jQuery equivalent is.)

Answer (score 1):

If the image src is not present, browser will display the alt or the title image. As you have classes having background image, you do not need the `img` element. Hence, you can update your html to

```
<div class="left" id="mToggle" style="height:64px;width:64px" title="new toggle button" />
```

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/os7svkw1/5/

Answer (score 1):

It's because your image doesn't have the `src` attribute set, in which case it displays the `alt` or the `title` attribute instead of the image. The image you put in is a css `background-image` which is not the same as using an `input type="image"` tag with the `src` set.

If you still want to keep your `css` then use something else, like a `div`:

```
<div class="left" id="mToggle" title="new toggle button"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lucianmoldovan/os7svkw1/6/

Otherwise set the `src` attribute of the `input type="image"` tag.